# Fill select with values from JSON does not work

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to fill a `select` with values coming from JSON and does not work. I created a [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezTdEp1cUspfvdZoInIK) for testing purpose. In the same code I'm trying to setup the selected value by default and this doesn't work either, what is wrong in my code? I just copied and paste another working code I have and change vars, nothing else (Angular is driving me crazy)

Comment: Stick with it, once Angular clicks for you it will all be worth it, it truly is an amazing framework to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added ng-app for angular to bootstrap ,changed ng-options for showing the select control properly and finally init `$scope.docRifStatus` object for default value by binding to ng-model..

**Example:**

html:

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="docRifStatus" ng-options="st.name for st in mediastatus"></select>
  </body>
```

js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var elements = {
    "mstatus": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Activo"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Inactivo"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Pendiente"
    }],
    "official_document": [{
      "type": "2",
      "status": "3",
      "url": "wuelto_5332893babc1b6.55975109.jpeg"
    }, {
      "type": "3",
      "status": "3",
      "url": "wuelto_5332893c750790.56043469.jpeg"
    }]
  };

  $scope.mediastatus = elements.mstatus;
  $scope.docRifStatus = $scope.mediastatus[0];
});
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8MmEuFAPPrzGeGGu6GR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**What you want to do**

You want this entity of `mediastatus`:

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Pendiente"
}

to be selected with the comprehension expression `st.id as st.name for st in mediastatus`. That is to say matching the ng model view value with the `id` property of the entity.

**What you do wrong**

You bind the ng model on `docRifStatus` which is "3", not 3. That's the whole problem.

**Fast solution**

Try setting your `docRifStatus` at controller init time with:

```
$scope.docRifStatus = +elements.official_document[0].status;
```

**Best practice**

Add a directive which pushes a parser function in the `ngModelController.$parsers` array and a formatter function in the `ngModelController.$formatters` array.

The parser will return a number from the string input i.e. "3" -> 3.

The formatter will do the exact opposite.

This way, the id in the model will always be a string while the one that is matched by ngOptions will be the formatted number. Selecting a value will select a number id which will be parsed to be set on the model.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1) You forgot [ngApp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

2) `elements.official_document[0].status` value is actually a string in your json and not an int. Since you are tracking by `mstatus.id` which is an int it did not match for the initial value. Changing your `elements.official_document` `status` properties to int fixed this issue.

[Updated Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfWCXKAT4EmHWgrYHm8z?p=preview)